# PySpark : Find Excess quantity in table

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Very new to pyspark/pandas need help.

I have a table Table 1 that looks something like this

```
-----------------
Id    ID2   qty 
-----------------
A1    S1     5
A2    S1     5
A3    S2     10
----------------
```

I have a table Table 2 that looks something like this

```
-----------------
ID2   totalQty 
-----------------
S1     15
S2     10
----------------
```

My result should be

```
-----------------
ID2   qty 
-----------------
S1     5
S2     0
----------------
```

I tried joining both table and I am able to find the row that nap to zero  but dont know how find that row with excess quantity

```
result_df = table1.join(table2, "ID2", "left").withColumn('remainingQty', F.col('totalQty') - F.col('qty'))
```

the result_df I get is

```
----------------------------------------
Id    ID2   qty  totalQty  remainingQty
----------------------------------------
A1    S1     5     15       10
A2    S1     5     15       10
A3    S2     10    10       0
-----------------------------------------
```

I know the first two row in the above table are wrong. need help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to sum `qty` by `ID2` in table1 before joining it with table2, as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result_df = table1.groupBy('ID2').agg(F.sum('qty').alias('qty')) \
    .join(table2, 'ID2') \
    .select(F.col('ID2'), (F.col('totalQty') - F.col('qty')).alias('qty'))
```

And with your input table1 and table2, you will get the following `result_df`:

```
+---+---+
|ID2|qty|
+---+---+
|S2 |0  |
|S1 |5  |
+---+---+
```